# Adding model mapping with Lambda Expression

Tags: generics, lambda, ef-code-first, factory-pattern

I have a mapping interface that goes like this:

```
public interface IMapping<T> where T: class, IEntityModel
{
    IQueryable<U> Project<U>(IQueryable<T> set) where U : class, IModel;
}
```

If I want to instantiate specific mapping, I do it with:

```
public class UserMapping : IMapping<User>
{
    .... code that contains mapping between IEntityModel and IModel
}
```

Now I want to register all the mappings in the global.asax application_start and have my base repository use them to project to view models with generic methods. This is how my mapping resolver works right now:

```
public static class MappingResolver
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, object>(); 

    public static void RegisterMapping<T, U>(U UMapping) where T: class, IEntityModel where U : IMapping<T> 
    {
        Mappings.Add(typeof(T), UMapping);
    }

    public static IMapping<T> GetMapping<T>() where T : class, IEntityModel
    {
        return Mappings[typeof(T)] as IMapping<T>;
    }
}
```

And it works just fine, except I don't like how adding of one mapping to resolver looks like:

```
MappingResolver.RegisterMapping<User, UserMapping>(new UserMapping());
```

What am I aiming to accomplish is syntax such as (syntax might not be right at all, it's just to depicit the idea):

```
MappingResolver.RegisterMapping((x,y) => {User, new UserMapping()});
```